# 'Mirroring' a two-dimensional array [Java]

Tags: java, arrays

I am attempting to make "2-dimensional" array in Java that populates itself with random numbers between 1 and 6 (EDIT: I meant 0 and 5, as the code does currently - my apologies). However, I would like the numbers to be 'mirrored' over an imaginary line-of-best-fit, as if dealing with a graph. For example, if the number at indicies [1][4] is 3.0, I would like the number at [4][1] to also be 3.0. The snippet of code I currently have that deals with this is below, for what its worth (I have array.length established as 6 at another point in the code):

```
Random random = new Random();

        int n = array.length;

        double [][] populationArray = new double [n][n];

        for (int i=0; i<populationArray.length; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<populationArray[i].length; j++) {
                populationArray[i][j] = random.nextInt(6);
                if (populationArray[i][j] != 0) {
                    populationArray[j][i] = populationArray[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        for (double[] p : populationArray) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p));
        }
```

This currently prints as:

```
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 5.0, 2.0]
[1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0]
[2.0, 5.0, 4.0, 1.0, 4.0, 1.0]
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 4.0, 2.0, 2.0]
[5.0, 3.0, 0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 4.0]
[2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 1.0]
```

As you can see some of the numbers reflect and some don't (I suspect the ones that do are purely out of luck), and I'm struggling with the logic of this. I would appreciate any suggestions - if this has been addressed somewhere else I'd also take a link, as I could not find it myself.

Thank you.

Comment: `if(populationArray[i][j] != 0)` appears to be your problem. It's essentially random if it will reflect or not. Also, you're overwriting previously reflected values with random numbers.

Comment: Apart from the 0.0 values array is actually mirrored like you say it should be. Remove the if condition and it should work fine.

Comment: your loops cover *all*positions in your array, but they should only cover *half* of all array position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the `if(populationArray[i][j] != 0)` only the values that aren't 0 are mirrored. if you remove the if statment the code will work.

Also random.nextInt(6) will generate an integer between 0 (inclusive) and 6 (exclusive), so that will generate either 0,1,2,3,4 or 5.

So to generate a number 1-5 (inclusive) you'll have to do random.nextInt(5)+1

So the for loop will become:

```
for (int i=0; i<populationArray.length; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<populationArray[i].length; j++) {
            populationArray[i][j] = random.nextInt(5)+1;
            populationArray[j][i] = populationArray[i][j];
    }
}
```

However I'd like to point out that all of the positions are given a random value twice. For creating a single 6x6 array the difference won't be very noticeable. But if you are planning to create bigger/many arrays I'd advise to optimise your code to avoid giving each spot in the array a value twice.

You can optimize this by changing `j<populationArray[i].length` to `j<=i`:

```
for (int i=0; i<populationArray.length; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<=i; j++) {
        populationArray[i][j] = random.nextInt(5)+1;
        populationArray[j][i] = populationArray[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: but it will take twice as much time as it is needed. OK, it is not a problem here, but it should be mentioned.

Comment: This worked perfectly - I should have said it, but compile time is not a factor I'm worrying about. Thank you!

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that looping over half of the array uses slightly less code too. Just swap `j<populationArray[i].length` with `j<=i`.

Comment: @Luke, that has caused only the points at [0][0], [1][1], [2][2], etc to be populated, with the rest as 0s. Not sure what I'm missing?

Comment: @Juniper Luke's sugestion is correct, I'll edit it in in my answer so you can see what you did wrong.

Comment: @Juniper it sounds like you might've combined two answers - it would only visit the main diagonal ("the middle") if you did something like `j=i;j<=i;j++` - which would be incorrect. I.e. it should be `for (int j=0; j<=i; j++) {`

Comment: @Luke, that was exactly it, I was a bit too zealous in my changes. Thank you.

Comment: @Juniper no problem - I'd reccommend accepting/ upvoting/ both this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with these lines

```
populationArray[i][j] = random.nextInt(6);
if(populationArray[i][j] != 0) {
    populationArray[j][i] = populationArray[i][j];
}
```

if `populationArray[i][j] = random.nextInt(6);` returns 0 than it will not be reflected.  I suspect you want `populationArray[i][j] = random.nextInt(5)+1;` this will return a random number between 1 and 6.

Bonus:  your code will now work but it is actually writing each cell twice.  It will write [1, 4] and mirror to [4, 1] but then it will continue looping and write over [4, 1] and mirror to [1, 4] to fix this you will want to add a check to see if it's 0 before writing to it. Which coincidentally just ends up moving your if statement one line up.

```
    for (int i=0; i<populationArray.length; i++){
        for (int j=i; j<populationArray[i].length; j++) {
            populationArray[i][j] = random.nextInt(5)+1;
            populationArray[j][i] = populationArray[i][j];
        }
    }
```

EDIT:  changed the solution based on Luke's comment.  Note the change to `int j=i` on the second for statement.

Comment: I would consider this a bit of a hack - it would be better to just loop over half of the array only (i.e. something like `j<=i` would do that).

Comment: I did want to 0s in there, so that it designates random double numbers between 0 and 5. It was just my logic that was off I think - I was assuming that it would populate the indicies with 0 unless otherwise specified, so that portion wouldn't need to be reflected. I don't know why it didn't occur to me to just reflect them all regardless.

Thank you for the note on efficiency - that has never been my strong suit but your explanantion makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Juniper Based on Luke Briggs comment, I would just change the second for loop so that it only iterates over half the array.

Comment: Either `for (int j=0; j<=i; j++)` or `for (int j=i; j<populationArray[i].length; j++)` would do that; one is generating the top half and reflecting to the bottom; the other is generating the bottom half and reflecting to the top.

Answer (score -1):

In case your arrays get larger you might want to save time by not setting each element twice. Therefore your inner loop should not run until `populationArray[i].length`

```
for (int i=0; i<populationArray.length; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<populationArray[i].length-i; j++) {
            populationArray[i][j] = random.nextInt(6);
            int oppositI = populationArray.length -1 - i;
            int oppositJ = populationArray[i].length -1 - j;
            populationArray[oppositI][oppositJ] = populationArray[i][j];
    }
}
```

This assumes that your `populationArray` is a sqare. It will be kinda more complex otherwise...

Comment: I'm rather sure this is incorrect - it would cause a chunk of the array to never be visited. The correct form is `j<=i` rather than `j<populationArray[i].length-i`.